# css:before : align multiple line of texts with image

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I display text after image with css:before

How can I align vertically the text, specially when there are multiple lines of text ?

See my snippet

```css
.link-container {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.link-container:before {
  vertical-align: inherit;
  content: url("http://via.placeholder.com/50x50");
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p class="link-container">
  <a class="text-download" href="#">Link#1</a>
</p>

<p class="link-container">
  <a class="text-download" href="#">Link#2</a><br>
  <a class="text-download" href="#">Link#3</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Why the downvote ? Ok, I should have explained what i’ve tried to do before (I tried with  `vertical-align: middle;` which could work). It would be nice when you donwvote to explain why the question is not good : it could help me to improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the image as background then you can easily center the content using flexbox for example:

```css
.link-container {
  padding-left: 55px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/50x50") left center/50px 50px no-repeat;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  
}
```

```html
<p class="link-container">
  <a class="text-download" href="#">Link#1</a>
</p>

<p class="link-container">
  <a class="text-download" href="#">Link#2</a>
  <a class="text-download" href="#">Link#3</a>
</p>

<p class="link-container">
  <a class="text-download" href="#">Link#2</a>
  <a class="text-download" href="#">Link#3</a>
  <a class="text-download" href="#">Link#4</a>
</p>
```